# Большой Insert с другой базы

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql

Необходимо вставить данные из select из другой базы. Количество записей более 5 млн. Таблицы полностью идентичны. По линке соответственно идет сбой при переполнении буфера. Можно ли передавать данные в цикле небольшими порциями, или же реализовать все через rest modules?
Ниже упрощенный пример запроса.

```
 insert into table1 
 (select * from table2@dblink where code_firme
 CODE_FIRME between 2000 and 2050);
```

Comment: Можно, но пока не понятно, зачем. Какой идет сбой, при переполнении какого буфера?

Comment: На работе такая задача собрать данные из 2-х таблиц они на разных базах в одну на третьей(все таблицы одинаковы), но с определенными условиями. Т.е. все данные абсолютно мне не нужны. Пишет буфер переполнен.

Comment: Ещё раз, какой буфер переполнен, код ошибки?

Comment: Ну сделайте порциями, почему нет. Я как-то такое тоже делал, когда записей были миллионы. Просто потому, что это копирование лочило надолго таблицы, а это было нехорошо, поэтому копировал порциями. Да ещё и с использованием временных таблиц делал.

Answer (score 2):

Tак должно работать:

```sql
create database link loopback connect to me identified by me using 'localhost/pdb1'
/
create table t1 as 
    select level id, lpad ('A', 4000, 'A') memo from dual connect by level<=10e3
/
create table t2 as select * from t1 where 1=0
/  
insert /*+ append */ into t2
select * from t1@loopback 
where 1=1 -- добавте условия фильтра
/
10,000 rows inserted.

commit;
```

Если сетевое соединение неустойчивое или имеет ещё какие-либо ограничения, то записывайте данные порциями:

```sql
declare n number := 0; 
begin
    loop
        insert /*+ append */ into t2
        select * from t1@loopback 
        where 1=1 -- добавте условия фильтра
        and not exists (select 0 from t2 where id = t1.id)
        and rownum<=1000; -- подберите значение
        exit when sql%rowcount = 0;
        n := n + sql%rowcount; 
        commit;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line (n||' rows inserted.'); 
end;
/
10000 rows inserted.
```

Comment: Спасибо сегодня реализую. Результат дополнительно прокоментирую.

Comment: Сразу же, даже при значении rownum<=1 сразу же ошибка.  PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values

Comment: И по этой строке  and not exists (select 0 from t2 where id = t1.id)    он отсекает мол не знаю что такое id, хотя свои переменные я подставил.

Comment: Я вам дал воспроизводимый пример. Понятно, что реальные данные отличаются, и тут необходима внимательность при переносе кода. Нет колонки id, надо заменить на CODE_FIRME, если это первичный ключ в вашей таблице.  _хотя свои переменные я подставил_, куда вы их подставили (?), в моём примере нет ни одной переменной (кроме n).

Comment: Исправил. нашел первичный ключ в таблице. Подставил его значение. Но все равно сразу ошибка PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values

Comment: Ну это совсем просто, ваши таблицы не совпадают по кол-ву колонок. В таблицу на удалённой БД добавили колонку.